# <interactive>:8:7: error: Variable not in scope: ys :: [a]

Tags: haskell

```
ys = [1,2,3,4,5]
last' xs = head (reverse xs)
```

I wrote this simple function in Haskell using Vscode to get the last element in list.

when I tried to run it on GHCI there was a compilation  error:

```
*Main> last' xs
<interactive>:2:7: error: Variable not in scope: xs :: [a]
```

I don't know how to fix it .

Comment: Please include *code*, not *images of code*: see [*Why not upload images of code errors when asking a question*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). [edit] the question and include code fragments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you try to run `last' xs`, note that `xs` is just a name the argument is bound to in the `last'` function definition, and there is no "variable" with such a name outside the scope of the function itself. You should use the name the list is bound to, namely `ys`, i.e.  `last' ys`:

```
ghci> ys = [1,2,3,4,5]
ghci> last' xs = head (reverse xs)
ghci> last' ys
5
```

Keep in mind that this solution works only with non-empty lists, because `head` function is *partial* and do not return normally on empty list (throws an exception).